# Battery drains even with app off screen, could it be Location Services doing it?

Tags: android

I run my app, which uses GPS and Bluetooth, then hit the back button so it goes off screen. I verified via LogCat that the app's onDestroy was called. OnDestroy removes the location listeners and shuts down my app's Bluetooth service. I look at the phone 8 hours later and half the battery charge has been consumed, and my app was responsible according the phone's Battery Use screen. If I use the phone's Settings menu to Force Stop the app, this doesn't occur. So my question is: do I need to do something more than remove the listeners to stop Location Services from consuming power? That's the only thing I can think of that would be draining the battery to that degree when the app is supposedly dormant.

Here's my onStart() where I turn on the location-related stuff and Bluetooth:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(D_GEN) Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity onStart, adding location listeners");

    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // setupBluetooth() will then be called during onActivityResult
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        // Otherwise, setup the Bluetooth session
    } else {
        if (mBluetoothService == null) 
            setupBluetooth();
    }
    // Define listeners that respond to location updates
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, GPS_UPDATE_INTERVAL, 0, this);    
    mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
    mLocationManager.addNmeaListener(this);

}
```

And here's my onDestroy() where I remove them:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(D_GEN) Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity onDestroy, removing update listeners");
    // Remove the location updates
    if(mLocationManager != null) {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this); 
        mLocationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(this);
        mLocationManager.removeNmeaListener(this);
    }
    if(D_GEN) Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity onDestroy, finished removing update listeners");
    if(D_GEN) Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity onDestroy, stopping Bluetooth");
    stopBluetooth();
    if(D_GEN) Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity onDestroy finished");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the GPS listeners and Bluetooth on OnStart and removing them on onDestroy(). This may result in calling several times the listeners and bluetooth initialization without having stop them first, if your activity goes on Stop status (because you started another activity) and then returned to the one that does the initialization, without havin onDestroy called.

However, I believe that this is not causing issues with the GPS, because you defining the listener within the activity only once, and I expect the GPS listeners adding routine to test and avoid adding twice the same listener. Also, if the GPS is running after you exit the application you should see the GPS icon in the phone top status bar.

You are not showing the code for the bluetooth, so there you may have a problem.

Maybe moving your initialization code to the onResume() and stoping code to the onPause() will solve the issue, otherwise you will need to make a test to avoid two consecutive initializations witout a stoping.

good luck.

Comment: I've looked at the status icons while the app is running and after the onDestroy() is called, and the GPS icon is present while it's running and gone after onDestroy() is called. Good tip to check that.